# About task notepad registers in pSOS

Tags: rtos

In the pSOS RTOS each task has notepad registers. What is the purpose of Task Notepad registers?

How many task notepad registers will be associated with each tasks?

In what circumstances might notepad registers be useful (for example, will this be used in [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) or memory management, etc.?).

Comment: what are "notepad registers"?

Comment: I don't think there is any such thing as a "notepad register" in vxworks

Comment: Perhaps the confusion came from WindRiver's aquisition and subsequent abandonment of pSOS in favour of their own VxWorks?  There was talk of a ["convergence" compatibility layer](http://www.embedded.com/print/4219411) in 2000 when the acquisition occurred; I don't know if that ever occurred, but possibly that included notepad registers? I imagine that it was only ever available to existing pSOS customers if it did happen.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is specific to pSOS and described in the [documentation](http://read.pudn.com/downloads18/doc/project/63725/PSOS/PSOS_C1.PDF):

[image]

So essentially they are nothing more that a block of shared-memory stored in the TCB of each task.  They are not *registers* in the usual sense of the term.

I guess they provide a simple if somewhat limited means of IPC through shared memory, but on a 32bit system, access to 32bit memory objects is already atomic, so it is not clear what advantage they provide over a static variable with accessors as follows:

```
static volatile uint32_t shared = 0 ;
uint32_t getShared(){ return shared ; }
void setShared( uint32_t val ){ shared = val ; }
```

This roll-your-own approach has advantages over the use of notepad registers; for example you can add range-checking or other validation, and you have a single place to put a break-point should you need to trap either all read or all write accesses to the data.  You could even make one or other of the accessors private to the a task, so that externally the data has either read-only or write-only semantics making for a more robust system where such semantics are applicable.

So essentially I see few advantages in using notepad registers, and as they are specific to pSOS their use only complicates portability to other systems.  This is especially true given that [pSOS is largely obsolete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSOS_%28real-time_operating_system%29).

Answer (score 0):

I have used these registers in the past. Normally used to pass a pointer to a task needing information. The technique was

- sending task:

  ```
  t_setreg(INFO_REG_ID, task_id,(u32)&info);
  ev_send(INFO_REG_EVENT, task_id);
  ```
- receiving task:

  ```
  ev_receive(INFO_REG_EVENT,...);
  info = (info_struct *)t_getreg(INFO_REG_ID...);
  ```

The syntax of the of the pSOS call are probably not be correct, I don't have my manuals in front of me. But I think you get the drift. I found it cleaner than passing messages via the queues.

Answer (score -1):

Each task has 16 software notepad 32-bit registers. They are carried in a task’s TCB and can be set and read using the t_setreg and t_getreg calls, respectively.

The purpose of these registers is to provide to each task, in a standard system-wide manner, a set of named variables that can be set and read by other tasks, including by remote tasks on other processor nodes.

Eight of these notepad registers are reserved for system use. The remaining eight can be used for any application-specific purpose.

Comment: Are you sure this is vxworks? I cant find any reference to notepad registers, or the t_setreg and t_getreg calls. These dont even conform to the vxworks naming convention

Comment: Sorry this is not vxworks. This is PSOS. But vxworks provides TCB extensions where we can have notepad registers so that migration from psos to vxworks will be of no difference.Existing functionality based on notepad registers in psos will not be impacted after moving to vxworks.

Comment: I think you should really either delete this question, or reword both it and the answer, and add the correct tags. As currently presented, your question and answer suggest that vxworks has these notepad registers, and calls t_setreg and t_getreg, when it doesnt.

Comment: Hi leave vxworks but the  concept of notepad register is there in RTOS right. so i think my quesion is still valid.

Comment: So you have answered your own question (by copying the documentation verbatim); is there anything you don't understand and still need advice on?